# How to access nested objects then $sum a field through MongoDB Aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, discord.js, nosql, aggregation-framework

I need to get the total points (sum) of all members. It should return an output of: **_id: "team 1", points: 14**

I tried using this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      team: "Team 1"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "team 1",
      points: {
        $sum: "$members.points"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It's incorrect. This is supposed to be for node js/discord.js. Should I just hard code in js an array and fill it with the values from this MongoDB document to get the sum? If I could get the sum through querying on MongoDB I think it'd be better.

This is the document.

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "0123456789"
  },
  "team": "Team 1",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Ryan",
      "points": 4
    },
    {
      "type": "Josh",
      "points": 8
    },
    {
      "type": "Angelo",
      "points": 2
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is only 1 document per team, no need to group.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      team: "Team 1"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      team: 1,
      _id: 0,
      points: {
        $sum: "$members.points"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u7AnHoZfwan)